# Блок Html in JSP как тег

Tags: java, html, jsp, tag

Задача в проекте создать свой тег в jsp.

Читаю разные туториалы, все показывают как создать пустой тег.

Суть такова, хочу создать тег в котором будет весь мой хеадер страницы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
В меню есть подсвеченный элемент, соответственно надо тег с параметром например подавать 1,2,3 и т.д.

чтобы было что то типа `<h:header>1</h:header>` - нарисует хеадер и выделит первую вкладку

Как поместить в свой тег часть HTML и при этом еще и с параметром?

Comment: Гляньте тут: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы тэг был не пустой - в него надо поместить тело, которое потом будет обрабатываться обработчиком и печатать HTML.

Примерно такое и написано в [тюториале](http://javatutor.net/articles/custom-tags-in-jsp-pages).

> Пользовательский тег между своими началом и концом может содержать пользовательский или базовый тег, элементы сценариев, HTML